# When I click on my site in the Google results, I get redirected to my site with an extra www subdomain which is an error

Tags: seo, google-search

I have this domain example.com, when I search in Google for "example" I can see it has listed my domain properly. But when I click on that it goes to `https://www.www.example.com` with two `www` segments. I have configured Google web-master accounts as well. What could be the reason it got `www` segment twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with Google.  Your site is not redirecting properly:

```
$ curl --head http://www.example.com/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 18 Jan 2016 13:09:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://www.www.example.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

You are issuing an `https` redirect with `www.www` in it when `http` is specified.

When you fix it, you may also want to add the `www.www` record to DNS and point it to your web server. You might want to use a CNAME record.  That is most likely what you do with the `www` record.  Then you can configure your web server to redirect `www.www` to your site.